# Selenium drop down option unable to web scrape

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I have to web scrape the info of car year, model and make from https://auto-buy.geico.com/nb#/sale/vehicle/gskmsi/ (if the link doesn't work, kindly go to 'https://geico.com', fill in the zip code as '75002', enter random details in customer info and you will land up in the vehicle info link).

Having browsed through various answers, I have figured out that I can't use mechanize or something similar owing to the browser sending JavaScript requests every time I select an option in the menu. That leaves something like Selenium to help me.

Following is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Ie("IEDriverServer.exe")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://auto-buy.geico.com/nb#/sale/customerinformation/gskmsi')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('vehicleYear'))
print(select)
```

The output is an empty [] because it's unable to locate the form.

Please let me know how to select the data from the forms of the page.

P.S.: Though I have used IE, any code correction using Mozilla or Chrome is also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to fill out all the info in "Customer" tab using Selenium and then wait for the appearance of this select element:

   ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support import ui


   select_element = ui.Select(ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "vehicleYear"))))
   ```
2. Then select a needed option:

   ```
   select_element.select_by_visible_text("2017")
   ```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Hey, it's showing error in the last line as select_element doesn't have 'select_by_visible_text()' .
I tried rewriting it as(after importing "from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
"): 
Select(select_element).select_by_visible_text("2017") but unfortunately it returns none

Comment: @NikhilNair, sorry, I have updated my answer. Check it now, please.

Comment: Thank you so much. It has helped.
I am a little naïve in selenium. I don't want the exact code but can you tell me how to proceed after the above step as in what exactly should I extract to get the model and make of car?

Comment: @NikhilNair, you can add simple wait `time.sleep(2)` after first selection and then select another elements step by step.

Comment: @NikhilNair, if my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Comment: Hey
It's giving a timeout exception. Any other way?

Comment: @NikhilNair, you need to do an action from the answer and then add a wait. After that locate next select element and select needed option (here шt is not necessary to use `WebDriverWait` for that).

Comment: One final question and then I will close this comment thread.
now the problem is that sleep is working but now it's unable to locate the next element. For eg: When I add "time.sleep(5)
select_element.select_by_visible_text("Acura")" , it shows error - "Could not locate element with visible text: Acura" .
Thanks in advance

Comment: @NikhilNair, how have you located the next element? Give me a code.

Comment: This much only I have written after the code from your answer:- 
time.sleep(5) 
select_element.select_by_visible_text("Acura")


Also to retrieve data from page, I am supposed to use 'select_element' variable rght? Or some other element

Comment: @NikhilNair, now, you can use the same variable, but you need to assign a new value to him (with another `By.ID`) because you want to use another select element.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.
I assume now that I extract data using beautiful soup ,rght?